# Rewrite index.php?foo=bar&amp;bar=foo to index.php?foo=bar&bar=foo

Tags: php, apache, html, .htaccess, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and its mostly good. Although there are a few errors.

For example; I put in my HTML `&amp;` instead of `&` like you're meant to. jQuery doesn't read it properly and when it shows it in the url has `&amp;` showing instead of `&` like its meant to.

For example

```
<a href="index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false">Hello</a>
```

It will go to

```
 example.com/index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false
```

when really it should go to

```
 example.com/index.php?foo=true&bar=false
```

It's really annoying and I use lots of them so I cannot manally write a .htaccess because all the get variables change and it would be a very long file it I did write every possible foo and bar.

My question is: Is there a quick way for an apache server to correct `&amp;` to `&`?

Comment: Are you passing your HTML through something like `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` before outputting it? If you've already included an `&amp;` entity in your "raw" HTML, and then you pass it through one of those functions, by default you'll double-encode that entity, which would make a browser see the URLs as *actually* containing `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false`, when used as an attribute's value, is decoded as `index.php?foo=true&bar=false` by the browser.

So, clicking on this link:

```
<a href="index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false">Hello</a>
```

Goes to `index.php?foo=true&bar=false`, not `index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false`.

This is because `&` is a special character in HTML, and `&amp;` is how you can encoded it to remove its special meaning.

It's actually invalid to write `<a href="index.php?foo=true&bar=false">`, and perfectly valid to write `<a href="index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false">`.

---

If jQuery reads it wrongly, there must be a bug in jQuery, or you are doing something wrong.

If you have tons users of using doing requests to `index.php?foo=true&amp;bar=false`, you may want to rewrite the request like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD) (.*)&amp;(.*) HTTP/[\d.]+$
RewriteRule %2&%3 [R]
```

(Using RewriteCond and matching on %{THE_REQUEST} because a RewriteRule won't match on the query string.)

This will redirect the user to the URL with `&amp;` decoded to `&`. If there is multiple `&amp;`, there will be multiple redirects.